How can we adjust BT table data-height based on screen size?
Can we adjust BT table data height based on screen size no need to page scroll bar vertical and horizontal .
table size auto adjust based on screen size.
I am using Django template.
Thanks,
Gaurav Goyal
try bootstrap5 table response class and add data-height property to bt table

I set height property based on window size:-
$('#table_id').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({       height: getHeight(),    }) function getHeight() {     return $(window).height()-180; }
